# How can I get any character after url

Tags: php

Greetings I'm trying to make a redirect if the URL is empty like this https://localhost/redirectv2.php
to another URL example https://stefan-momcilovic.com but if I have something like https://localhost/redirectv2.php/about-me or something else then redirect will not happen

```
<?php

$url = 'https://localhost/redirectv2.php';


if(strpos($url, '/') !== false && strpos($url, "/a") === false) {
    header('Location: https://stefan-momcilovic.com');
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I finally solved it!

```
<?php

$url = 'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$parseUrl = parse_url($url);
$params = array_values(array_filter(explode('/', $parseUrl["path"])));


if(strpos($url, '/') !== false && count($params) == 0) {
    header('Location: https://stefan-momcilovic.com');
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```php
$url = 'https://localhost';

$parsedUrl = parse_url($url);
    
if (!$parsedUrl["path"]) {
  header('Location: https://stefan-momcilovic.com');
}
```

Comment: That's not it please

Comment: path would be `/redirectv2.php` for what he's asking.

Comment: The `path` doesn't necessarily need to be empty, it could also be `/` so you would need to check for that as well. That would have answered the OP's initial question, but now they've changed it. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that will give you what you need and have support for multiple urls.

```
<?php
    $url = 'https://localhost/redirectv2.php';
    $redirectUrls = [
        'https://localhost/redirectv2.php'
    ];

    if(in_array(trim($url, '/'), $redirectUrls)){
        header('Location: https://stefan-momcilovic.com');
    }
?>
```